# Necessity of filter in GNU makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have the following directory structure.

```
/home/user/
          ├── Makefile
          │ 
          ├── easy/
          │     └── a.cpp
          ├── medium/
          │       └── b.cpp
          └──  build/
```

My goal is to compile all `.cpp` files in `easy` and `medium` and create separate executables in `build`. The Makefile below achieves what I want (omitting the parts that are not relevant to my question). The part I do not understand is the necessity of the call to `filter` in line 6.

```
  1 SOURCEDIRS = easy medium
  2 TARGETDIR = build
  3 
  4 SOURCES = $(foreach dir,$(SOURCEDIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
  5 $(info $(SOURCES))
  6 TARGETS = $(foreach dir,$(SOURCEDIRS),$(patsubst $(dir)/%.cpp,$(TARGETDIR)/%.out,$(filter $(dir)/%,$(SOURCES))))
  7 $(info $(TARGETS))
```

Output:

```
# content of SOURCES
easy/a.cpp medium/b.cpp
# content of TARGETS
build/a.out build/b.out
```

Specifically, based on the the manual for `patsubst`, I would expect the call to `filter` to be redundant.

> **$(patsubst pattern,replacement,text)**
>
> Finds whitespace-separated words in text that match pattern and replaces them with replacement.

[source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)

E.g., I would expect the following Makefile to achieve my goal,

```
  1 SOURCEDIRS = easy medium
  2 TARGETDIR = build
  3 
  4 SOURCES = $(foreach dir,$(SOURCEDIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
  5 $(info $(SOURCES))
  6 TARGETS = $(foreach dir,$(SOURCEDIRS),$(patsubst $(dir)/%.cpp,$(TARGETDIR)/%.out,$(SOURCES)))
  7 $(info $(TARGETS))
```

though the contents of `TARGETS` are

```
# content of SOURCES
easy/a.cpp medium/b.cpp
# content of TARGETS
build/a.out medium/b.cpp easy/a.cpp build/b.out
```

What am I misunderstanding? Why do we need `filter` in this case?

Comment: The docs don't say anything about removing words.  They just say matching words are replaced.

Comment: I got it now, was thinking that pattern matching will work as a sieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`patsubst` doesn't delete the words that don't match the pattern.

`$(patsubst easy/%.cpp,build/%.out,easy/a.cpp medium/b.cpp)` is not `build/a.out`, it's `build/a.out medium/b.cpp`